# Why Does Electron React Passing Prop Uses Older State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, electron

So I am new to working on Electron and React. I wanted to implement more functionality but I have run into an issue where when I pass function c into a new Card element it seems to pass the hook in function c at the time of creation.

Such that:
When the + button is clicked 3 times it would render 3 Cards as expected, lets call them 0, 1
and 2.
However, when their log button is clicked to console log the cards hook, clicking 0's log button console
logs:

```
{}
```

clicking 1's log button console logs:

```
{0: {react element of 0}}
```

clicking 2's log button console logs:

```
{0: {react element of 0}, 1: {react element of 1}}
```

However, clicking the - button which i have rigged to troubleshoot this at the moment in the App.js produces:

```
{0: {react element of 0}, 1: {react element of 1}, 2: {react element of 2}}
```

Am I wrong to assume that clicking each log button should have instead console logged what the - button in the App.js console logged. Rather than what the hook looked like at the time of the Card elements creation? How would I go about fixing this issue?

Note: the reason why I use an Object to store the React elements instead of an Array is because I would like to eventually add a remove button to remove individual cards. Is there a better way to do what I am doing?

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Cards from './Cards/Cards'
import { useState } from 'react';

let KEY = 0

export default function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState({})

  const c = () => {
    console.log(cards)
  }
  const make = () =>{
    const a = <Cards log={c} anID={KEY}/>
    const b = {...cards}
    b[KEY] = a
    KEY += 1
    setCards(b)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="time-container">
        {Object.values(cards)}
      </div>
      <button className="add-button" onClick={() => make()} >+</button>
      <button className="" onClick={() => console.log(cards)} >-</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Card.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './Cards.css'

export default function Cards({ log, anID }) {
    return <div className="card-container">

        <div>

            <button className="card-buttons-red" onClick={()=> log(anID)}>Log</button>
            <button className="card-buttons">Edit</button>

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You should probably use an array, instead of an object, for cards.

Comment: You are using already created objects to view in your application. Therefore, `c` function signature won't be changed based on `cards` changes. For this you need to `map` your `Cards` component inside the component.

Comment: @Invizi My idea was to store the cards in an object so that I can identify them through their keys to add a remove function later

Comment: @KavinduVIndika I thought it `c`should point to the `cards` hook which should be at a specific pointer address. But I guess not.
How would I go about mapping the `Cards` component? Do you mean I should iterate through the object and reconstruct the elements? Because wouldn't that rerender the older cards and if I add a countdown timer or something to them it would potentially mess it up? Sorry if you could give me an example that would be great!

Comment: As @Invizi mentioned, it doesn't really matter whether you're creating array or objects. You should create `jsx elements` that you want to show in your application on the run.

Comment: What does the countdown timer do?

Comment: @KavinduVIndika I thought I do when the onClick function fires it calls `make` which creates a `<Cards log={c} anID={KEY}/>` which gets inserted into the `cards` Object hook which gets rendered in `{Object.values(cards)}`
Also I guess why I don't just create the jsx element into the main return is because I possibly want it to create an unlimited amount of cards, not a set amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way React works is that it re-runs your Component function whenever it re-renders (or even more frequently).

Then anything in the Component function body is recreated, to the exception of hooks which *may* retain some previous information.

In your case, that means your `c` function and your `cards` state variable are different references each time.

Then as implied by @KavinduVIndika's answer, you essentially *embed* these references when creating your child Cards components in your `make` function and storing them in your `cards` state. On next re-render, new references are created, leading to your symptom.

An immediate workaround could be to try referencing something that "persists" through rerenders but without being embedded. That is the use case for `useRef` hook.

```
function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState({})

  const c = useRef()

  c.current = () => {
    console.log(cards)
  }
  const make = () =>{
    const a = <Cards log={c} anID={KEY}/>
    const b = {...cards}
    b[KEY] = a
    KEY += 1
    setCards(b)
  }

  return <>(template)</>
}

// in Cards, call c.current
<button className="card-buttons-red" onClick={()=> log.current(anID)}>Log</button>
```

But as implied by @KavinduVIndika's comment, there is just a more common React way to avoid such issue completely. It seems to me that it may be due to your attempt of *premature optimization*, to anticipate your timer usage, but without knowing that React already covers for the most penalizing performance bottleneck, i.e. browser repaint, thanks to its Virtual DOM. Yes, your child Cards component may be re-run (but retain its states with proper usage of `ref` special prop), but in the vast majority of cases you see little performance impact.

```
function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState({})

  const c = () => {
    console.log(cards)
  }
  const make = () =>{
    const a = KEY // use plain data, do not store JSX
    const b = {...cards}
    b[KEY] = a
    KEY += 1
    setCards(b)
  }

  return (<>
    {Object.values(cards).map(cardData =>
      // by building the Cards within the App at render time,
      // it now uses the most up-to-date reference of your c function,
      // hence avoids past reference issue.
      // Performance-wise, React detects that the actual DOM
      // does not need visual update, hence no repaint.
      <Cards log={c} anID={cardData} ref={cardData} />
    )}
  </>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you created `<Cards log={c} anID={KEY} />` jsx element using `make()` function, it won't be changed again. Function signature of `c` won't be changed, based on the change of `cards` state when you insert into a particular `<Cards/>` component as a prop. That simply means, function parameters or its output won't be changed once you created the `<Cards/>` component.

That's why with 1st **Log** button it only logs `{}` and 2nd **Log** button logs `{0: {react element of 0}}`.

Here you can observe that the function signature of `c` function you passed into a child component hasn't been changed once after it's created.

To explain it simply.

Before, executing `make()` function for the first time, `cards` object is `{}`.
Then you can understand when you execute `make()` function first, passed `c` function will be as follows.

```
  const c = () => {
    console.log({})
  }
```

This won't be changed based on the change of `cards`.

When you execute `make()` for the 2nd time, passed `c` function will be as follows.

```
  const c = () => {
    console.log({0: {react element of 0}})
  }
```

I don't think you really need to log `cards` object inside `<Cards/>` component. Just log it inside the parent component whenever `cards` state changed using a `useEffect` as follows.

```
let KEY = 0;

export default function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState({});

  const c = () => {
    console.log(cards);
  };
  const make = () => {
    const a = <Cards log={c} anID={KEY} />;
    const b = { ...cards };
    b[KEY] = a;
    KEY += 1;
    setCards(b);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("cards: ", cards);
  }, [cards]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="time-container">{Object.values(cards)}</div>
      <button className="add-button" onClick={() => make()}>
        +
      </button>
      <button className="" onClick={() => console.log(cards)}>
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and clarifying this for me, however, if you place it into a useEffect, I think it changes the intent of what I wanted to do with c which was to console log the hook from an onClick within each card.
So does this mean the only way to do that is to reconstruct each Card when a new card is added to the hook?

Comment: Yes, there should be a way to re-render previously created `Cards` components whenever you execute `make()` function. Otherwise passed `c` function signature won't be changed.